# Get only name from Save File Dialog

Tags: c#, winforms, savefiledialog

How do I get file name only by using Save File Dialog?

```
    MessageBox.Show("File was created with name: " + SOME CODE HERE + 
        Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + 
        "You can find it at: " + Environment.NewLine + sfdNewFile.FileName);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileName;
```

You can call it with the parameter `sfdNewFile.FileName`

Comment: What if I need a file name with out extension?

Comment: System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension
More on the Path class [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Use:

System.IO.Path.[GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx)(sfdNewFile.FileName);

Example:

```
MessageBox.Show("File was created with name: " + SOME CODE HERE + 
        Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + 
        "You can find it at: " + Environment.NewLine + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(sfdNewFile.FileName));
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: @marc_s: I did that, unfortunately the formatting didn't work correctly.

Comment: @marc_s : Can you please check your edits when you make them? You broke the link to the relevant MSDN page. Thanks.